# AWS cloudfront cli not creating web distribution for custom origin with compress parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-cloudfront

I was looking to create AWS cloudfront web distribution using CLI, everything was working fine until I tried to add **"Compress": True** to the distribution's JSON.

Following is my configuration

```
 {
  "CallerReference": "string",
  "Aliases": {
            "Items": [
                "test.example.com"
            ],
            "Quantity": 1
        },
    "DefaultRootObject": "", 
     "Origins": {
            "Items": [
                {
                    "OriginPath": "", 
                    "CustomOriginConfig": {
                        "OriginProtocolPolicy": "match-viewer", 
                        "HTTPPort": 80, 
                        "HTTPSPort": 443
                    }, 
                    "Id": "Custom-example.com", 
                    "DomainName": "example.com"
                }
            ], 
            "Quantity": 1
        },
    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
            "TrustedSigners": {
                "Enabled": false, 
                "Quantity": 0
            }, 
            "TargetOriginId": "Custom-example.com", 
            "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all", 
            "ForwardedValues": {
                "Headers": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                }, 
                "Cookies": {
                    "Forward": "none"
                }, 
                "QueryString": false
            }, 
            "MaxTTL": 31536000, 
            "Compress": true,
            "SmoothStreaming": false, 
            "DefaultTTL": 86400, 
            "AllowedMethods": {
                "Items": [
                    "HEAD", 
                    "GET"
                ], 
                "CachedMethods": {
                    "Items": [
                        "HEAD", 
                        "GET"
                    ], 
                    "Quantity": 2
                }, 
                "Quantity": 2
            }, 
            "MinTTL": 0
        },
    "CacheBehaviors":  {
            "Quantity": 2,
            "Items": [            {
                        "TrustedSigners": {
                            "Enabled": false,
                            "Quantity": 0
                        },
                        "TargetOriginId": "Custom-example.com",
                        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
                        "ForwardedValues": {
                            "Headers": {
                                "Quantity": 0
                            },
                            "Cookies": {
                                "Forward": "none"
                            },
                            "QueryString": false
                        },
                        "MaxTTL": 31536000,
            "Compress": true,
                        "PathPattern": "*.jpeg",
                        "SmoothStreaming": false,
                        "DefaultTTL": 86400,
                        "AllowedMethods": {
                            "Items": [
                                "HEAD",
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "CachedMethods": {
                                "Items": [
                                    "HEAD",
                                    "GET"
                                ],
                                "Quantity": 2
                            },
                            "Quantity": 2
                        },
                        "MinTTL": 60
                    }
                    ,
                                {
                        "TrustedSigners": {
                            "Enabled": false,
                            "Quantity": 0
                        },
                        "TargetOriginId": "Custom-example.com",
                        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
                        "ForwardedValues": {
                            "Headers": {
                                "Quantity": 0
                            },
                            "Cookies": {
                                "Forward": "none"
                            },
                            "QueryString": false
                        },
                        "MaxTTL": 31536000,
            "Compress": true,
                        "PathPattern": "*.png",
                        "SmoothStreaming": false,
                        "DefaultTTL": 86400,
                        "AllowedMethods": {
                            "Items": [
                                "HEAD",
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "CachedMethods": {
                                "Items": [
                                    "HEAD",
                                    "GET"
                                ],
                                "Quantity": 2
                            },
                            "Quantity": 2
                        },
                        "MinTTL": 100
                    }
                    ]    
        },
    "CustomErrorResponses": {
            "Quantity": 0
        },
    "Comment": "my distro",
       "Logging": {
            "Bucket": "", 
            "Prefix": "", 
            "Enabled": false, 
            "IncludeCookies": false
        },
    "PriceClass": "PriceClass_100",
    "Enabled": true,
    "ViewerCertificate": {
            "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": true, 
            "MinimumProtocolVersion": "SSLv3"
        },
            "Restrictions": {
                "GeoRestriction": {
                    "Items": [
                            "IN",
                            "GB",
                            "IR"
                         ],
                    "RestrictionType": "whitelist",
                    "Quantity": 3 
                }
            },
    "WebACLId": ""
}
```

This is the error I get

If I remove the compress parameter It works fine.

**Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior: "Compress", must be one of: TargetOriginId, ForwardedValues, TrustedSigners, ViewerProtocolPolicy, MinTTL, AllowedMethods, SmoothStreaming, DefaultTTL, MaxTTL
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig.CacheBehaviors.Items[0]: "Compress", must be one of: PathPattern, TargetOriginId, ForwardedValues, TrustedSigners, ViewerProtocolPolicy, MinTTL, AllowedMethods, SmoothStreaming, DefaultTTL, MaxTTL
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig.CacheBehaviors.Items[1]: "Compress", must be one of: PathPattern, TargetOriginId, ForwardedValues, TrustedSigners, ViewerProtocolPolicy, MinTTL, AllowedMethods, SmoothStreaming, DefaultTTL, MaxTTL**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After raising a ticket with AWS I got to know that my cloudfront distribution JSON is absolutely fine, the thing which was giving  the headache was the CLI version

I was using AWS CLI version 1.9.12  while **compress**  supports only with CLI version >= 1.9.14